# LINQ Group By problem

Tags: vb.net, linq, dataset, group-by

I am using VB.NET and DataSets; I have two tables and a relation. I'm querying the first table, but I can't use `Group By` on any field of the table. Here's the error I am seeing:

> Definition of method 'GroupBy' is not accessible in this context

And my code is as follows:

```
Dim Groups = From n In dataSetTableAsEnumerable _
   Group By n.filedName  Into Group
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 2):

Imports System.Linq on the top of your vb code file.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell it which thing you're grouping, for example:

```
 Dim Groups = From n In dataSetTableAsEnumerable _
              Group n By n.filedName  Into Group _
              Select Group
```

In your case you need `Group n By` as opposed to just  `Group By`.

Comment: @aaa - What type is  `dataSetTableAsEnumerable`?